# ANR Input dispatching timed out (ActivityRecord does not have a focused window)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-anr-dialog

I got an ANR crash report with following "title":

`Input dispatching timed out (ActivityRecord{abcdefg com.mypackage/.my.subpackage.MyActivity t3125} does not have a focused window)`

The stacktrace of the main thread looks like this:

```
  #00  pc 000000000009ca68  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+8)
  #00  pc 0000000000019d88  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+184)
  #00  pc 0000000000019c68  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+112)
  #00  pc 0000000000112174  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long, int)+44)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:335)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:183)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7700)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:612)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:997)
```

And none of the stacktraces of all other threads contains any code of my app.

Unfortunately I can't find any information about that type of ANR. All ANRs described here on SO or somewhere else have the title "Waiting because no window has focus ..." or "Waiting to send non-key event because ...". Does anyone know what that ANR means and maybe where I should search for the problem?

Comment: Any answer on this?

Comment: I don't have an answer yet, but according to the upvotes I don't seem to be the only one with the question.

Comment: Out of interest, what devices have people been getting this ANR on? For me it was a device called 'Macau'. However, I get an unexpected error when trying to view this device, and I can't seem to find it in the device catalogue either.

Comment: @Auc I just got a crash report from a Samsung Galaxy A50

Comment: I have seen it just once, but the real weird thing is that the report says this is happening in the background!